# How to add new controller for new page ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have create a application with start page is `login.html`, in `login.html` page I have button login and when I click, it will show `menu.html` page.

But when I add new controller for `menu.html` page in `app.js` and `controller.js` it has an error.

Here is my code:

**app.js :**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {     cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('login',{
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })  
        .state('menu',{
            url:'/menu',
            templateUrl:'templates/menu.html'
            controller:'MenuCtrl'
        })
        .state('menu.search', {
            url: '/search',
            views: {
              'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
              }
            }
          });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
});
```

**controller.js:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','$state',function($scope,$state) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.login = function() {
        $state.go('menu');
    };

}])
.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    console.log("Hello member");
});
```

I shows error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in line : controller:'MenuCrtl'

How I can fix it or how I can add new controller for `menu.html` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you have missing the `comma` , due to this you got the error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in line : controller:'MenuCrtl'**.

Your app.js files need to update by following code

```
          angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
          .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
              if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {     cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
              }
              if(window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
              }
            });
          })
          .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
              $stateProvider
                  .state('login',{
                      url:'/login',
                      templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
                      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
                  })  
                  .state('menu',{
                      url:'/menu',
                      templateUrl:'templates/menu.html',//Here you have missing comma
                      controller:'MenuCtrl'
                  })
                  .state('menu.search', {
                      url: '/search',
                      views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                          templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
                        }
                      }
                    });

              $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
          });
```

Please look in this [link](http://Using%20The%20UI-Router%20To%20Navigate%20In%20Ionic%20Framework) to understand the router and Navigate In Ionic Framework.

Also check to here to understand the [sidemenu in ionic](http://mcgivery.com/understanding-ionics-side-menu/).

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: that is a comma

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your state config object of `menu` state, add the `comma` after templateUrl

```
.state('menu',{
        url:'/menu',
        templateUrl:'templates/menu.html',
        controller:'MenuCtrl'
    })
```